# Sentence formation, how do I explain why the second choice is better?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-difference, sentence-choice

> 1) the other three diseases are increasing **enormously all over the country**
>
> 2) the other three diseases are increasing **in an enormous rate all over the country**

I think the second option sounds, but how do I explain why?
Is the first option incorrect somehow?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking whether the first sentence is grammatical? Or if the second sentence is a better option?

Comment: I guess both. If the second option is indeed better, what makes it better? If the first sentence is not grammatical, what rule is it breaking? TY @Jacob

Comment: Also, did you write these sentences or did you read them somewhere?

Comment: I'm trying to help someone.  The first option was his writing and the second one would be my suggestion, but I want to be able to understand myself and explain to him why it sounds better to me @Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the sentences are ungrammatical, however they do sound unnatural.

First of all, "the other three diseases" contains an error, and the order of adjectives should be changed as in the following. This is because when ordering adjectives, we prefer numbers to go first.

> The *three other* diseases are increasing enormously all over the country.

Second, it seems both sentences contain an error with the verb "increase." A disease doesn't increase in a country; that doesn't make sense. From the rest of the sentence I assume you mean the number of cases of the three diseases is increasing, in which case we would say:

> The three three diseases are *spreading* enormously all over the country.

Now, the adverb "enormously." In the first sentence it is used quite awkwardly. "Enormous(ly)" tends to be used the describe physical size, although it still can describe greatness. Thus, your change of "enormously" to the prepositional construct "in an enormous rate" works much better. However, I would change "in" to "at:"

> The three other diseases are spreading *at* an enormous rate all over the country.

Finally, *all over the country." This phrase seems awkward as well. Although this phrase does describe that the disease is spreading, well, in all parts of the country, I would recommend you replace it with a different but similar phrase:

> The three other diseases are spreading at an enormous rate *across the country*.

And that could be your final sentence.